Transition Effect in Tailwind isn't Working
The duration is supposed to act as a fade transition between the images on the carousel, but it just appears without any effect.
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import img1 from '../Assets/img1.jpg'
import img2 from '../Assets/img2.jpg'
import img3 from '../Assets/img3.jpg'
import { BsChevronCompactLeft, BsChevronCompactRight } from 'react-icons/bs';

const Home = () =>{ 

    const imgslides =[
        {url:img1},{url:img2},{url:img3},
    ];

    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

    const prevSlide = () => {
      const isFirstSlide = currentIndex === 0;
      const newIndex = isFirstSlide ? imgslides.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;
      setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
    };
  
    const nextSlide = () => {
      const isLastSlide = currentIndex === imgslides.length - 1;
      const newIndex = isLastSlide ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
      setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
    };
    return(
        <div name='Home' className='w-full h-screen bg-[#a34848]'>
             <div className='max-w-[1400px] h-[780px] w-full m-auto py-24 px-4 relative group'>
           <div
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imgslides[currentIndex].url})` }}
        className='w-full h-full rounded-2xl bg-center bg-cover transition-all duration-500'
      ></div>
       {/* Left Arrow */}
       <div className='hidden group-hover:block absolute top-[50%] -translate-x-0 translate-y-[-50%] left-5 text-2xl rounded-full p-2 bg-black/20 text-white cursor-pointer'>
        <BsChevronCompactLeft onClick={prevSlide} size={30} />
      </div>
      {/* Right Arrow */}
      <div className='hidden group-hover:block absolute top-[50%] -translate-x-0 translate-y-[-50%] right-5 text-2xl rounded-full p-2 bg-black/20 text-white cursor-pointer'>
        <BsChevronCompactRight onClick={nextSlide} size={30} />
      </div>
           </div>
        </div>
 
    )
}

export default Home

Am I missing something?
I originally had just the duration-500 line, but seeing as it didn't work, I added transition-all still to no effect.

You can't transition the background-image property.

so I can only do it to an image property.

This question is similar to: Cross-Fade between images with CSS in loop. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try using opacity transitions to do the same thing.
Add an array to track how visible each image is currently, then use Tailwind classes to transition.
Here's the useEffect hook you need:
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      nextSlide();
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [currentIndex]);

Then try putting this in place of the div with your current backgroundImages:
<div className='relative w-full h-full'>
  {imgslides.map((slide, index) => (
    <div
      key={index}
      style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slide.url})` }}
      className={`absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full rounded-2xl bg-center bg-cover transition-opacity duration-500 ${index === currentIndex ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0'
      }`}
    ></div>
  ))}
</div>

